# Shallow Copy Function for Child Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, shallow-copy

In building a GOAP system, I have a parent `Action` class that hold most of the logic used for planning, while children classes inherit from it to provide a small amount of their own functionality, such as `EatFoodAction`.

During planning, I need to create a shallow copy of an `Action` to act as a node in my action graph, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to write a `Copy()` function that can return a new instance of the child class, and not simply a new instance of the parent `Action` class.

It's not the copying fields that I can't do, it's the returning of a class of the right type.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283925/shallow-copy-from-inherited-classes) answer still requires overriding the copy function in each child class, something that I'd like to avoid.

A simple function to copy fields can only return the parent type, and I don't particularly want to create an override function for each child. A shallow copy will do just fine:

```
public class Action
{
    public Action Copy()
    {
        var newAction = new Action();
        // copy fields
        return newAction;
    }
}
```

The cloned action then gets passed into an `ActionNode(Action action)` class:

```
// planning code
var newNode = new ActionNode(oldAction.Copy())
```

I've tried generics, but they still need the exact type of the child class to work, and I'm not too sure how to use reflection without needing to the exact type to cast it to anyway.

How can I go about either returning the child class type, or is there some way to simply copy a class without needing to manually specify the exact type? Everything still inherits from the base `Action` class, so surely there is a way?

Thank you :)

Comment: .Net already has a shallow copy method: [MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0)

Comment: To use `MemberwiseClone()` implement your `Copy()` like so: `public Action Copy() => (Action) MemberwiseClone();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson this still requires a cast to type `Action`, but I need the clone to be of the child class type, such as `EatFoodAction`

Comment: The actual type returned will be the derived type, but of course you cannot define the return type in the base class as anything other than `Action`. Presumably your `Action` class has something like a virtual `PerformAction()` class that the derived classes implement? Calling that via the object returned from `Copy()` would call the derived version.

Comment: Depending on the runtime and C# version, you can leverage _covariant returns. Furthermore, you can define your type as a `record class` and gain this functionality implicitly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are absolutely correct, using your code does work! I thought that using `(Action)` would force the return to be of type `Action`, but it does indeed correctly return an object of the child type :)